# disassemble output :mov edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-28]

Tags: gdb

In the following output of  disassemble 28 is in decimal or hex ?
 mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-28]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the following output of disassemble 28 is in decimal or hex ? mov edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-28]

Very likely decimal. Is that output from GDB?

Newer versions of GDB use hex, and are explicit about it:

```
   0x000cadb6 <+6>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
```